# Using XML decorations to specify default values during de-serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, default-value, xml-deserialization

I have a problem deserializing some XML; the XML supplied by a third party is quite verbose, so if there is no value set for an particular element, it will supply and empty element (e.g. `<element1 />`).

This is a problem for certain elements, for example, those that are meant to store integers. I have control over the third party, so I could either get them to specify a default value (`<myinteger>0</myinteger>`) or I can get them to omit these elements entirely. Both of these should avoid the problem.

However, there may be situations in future, where we don't have so much control - in which case, is there a way of specifying, perhaps via a decoration, a default value?

```
    [XmlElement("myinteger")=0???]
    public int MyInteger
    {
        get
        {
            return myInteger;
        }
        set
        {
            myInteger= value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` *does* support `[DefaultValue]`, but it uses it during **serialization**. During *deserialization*, it simply runs the constructor, then takes incoming values and applies them. A common approach, then, is to use the constructor (or field-initializers):

```
public Foo() {
    Bar = 4;
}
[DefaultValue(4), XmlAttribute("bar")]
public int Bar {get;set;}
```

*However*; `XmlSerializer`'s interpretation of this is not "supply an empty element" - but rather "omit the element(/attribute)". Even `int?` doesn't map to "empty". To handle *empty* elements, you would have to handle it as a string. Which is ugly.

Comment: Hmmmm... simply getting the third party to omit empty elements of a description seems the easiest solution. I was just curious what I could do where I didn't have the luxury of that choice. I did consider the string option, but it is just an big can of worms...

Comment: There is at least one important effect during deserialization.  If the element is empty, without DefaultValue there may be a parsing error.  However, with it, the [generated code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) will skip the empty element.

Answer (score 0):

Decoration using [DefaultValue] doesn't seem to be complete solution since it doesnt work always. Another simple Solution (May not be clean)

```
public string _sourceSubFolderName;
    [DefaultValueAttribute("")]
    [XmlElement("SourceSubFolderName")]
    public string SourceSubFolderName
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sourceSubFolderName) ? 
               string.Empty : _sourceSubFolderName; }
        set { _sourceSubFolderName = value; }
    }
```