# C# Deserialize XML with missing tags

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization

I have a problem. I have the following XML:

```
<Data>
    <Images>
        <Image>
            <Id></Id>
            <Name></Name>
        </Image>
        <Image>
            <Id></Id>
            <Name></Name>
        </Image>
    </Images>
</Data>
```

And the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class MyData
{
    [XmlArray("Images")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Image")]
    public List<myImage> Images { get; } = new List<myImage>();
}

public class myImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}
```

But when I deserialize the XML using the following:

```
try
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
    var data = (MyData)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));

    App.lstAlbums = data.Albums;
    App.lstFotos = data.Fotos;
    App.lstFormaten = data.Formaten;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Give Error
}
```

I get the following error: `There was an error reflecting type 'MyApp.Models.MyData'`
The reason I get this error is because in the XML I don't have a tag for imageSource, while it is in the class. How can I deserialize the XML with the imageSource still in my class, but not in the XML?

Comment: You're also missing some end tags, so it's not valid XML.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but in my code I have valid XML. I will change it right now!

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the missing tag? I would have thought that it would just deserialize what it can and that property would just be `null`. If you comment out `imageSource` you're saying it works fine?

Comment: Yes, I have already comment the imageSource out and no crash then, but I need the imageSource, so that is the problem

Comment: Have you tried [DefaultAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmldefaultvalue?view=netframework-4.8) or [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492476/4121714)

Comment: Try to add the annotation ``[XmlIgnoreAttribute]``above the column.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The problem isn't with the XML, the problem is that `ImageSource` is abstract and so can't be serialized or deserialized.  In situations like this mark the property with `[XmlIgnore]` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581/3744182) to [XmlSerializer - There was an error reflecting type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60573/3744182).

Comment: In fact I'd say this is a duplicate of [XmlSerializer - There was an error reflecting type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60573/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @MohammedSAJID and @dbc already said, I had to add the Ignore tag to the fields in the class that aren't provided in the XML. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the DataMember attribute to specify which of your properties are going to be serialized (or loaded from the file), see link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `DataMember` is for `DataContractSerializer` but OP is using `XmlSerializer` so this won't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think XmlSerializer has an [XmlIgnore] attribute